# How I can know which class exception extended from?

Tags: java, exception

JVM only prints path in which exception class are. But how I can know class hierarchy in which `java.lang.NumberFormatException` is defined? For example Object->Throwable->Exception-RuntimeException->NumberFormatException.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Integer.parseInt("random text"); // // java.lang.NumberFormatException will occur
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)?

Comment: Do you mean how to find the class hierarchy while you're programming? You could look at the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html Or do you mean dynamically at run time,

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, I forgot about documentation